# What are the meaning and possible origin of "word!" and "word up"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang

Several times, I have had conversations, all over instant messenger, finish with "word" or "Word up G".

As it ends a conversation, I am guessing it is like "goodbye".

My question is what is the meaning of "word" and "word up g"? Also, what is the origin?

I am more interested in the meaning as that will help with understanding its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are generally used to mean "I agree." The terms are from late 1980s hip-hop slang. As Ed Guiness notes, popular usage probably originated with the single *Word Up!* by Cameo.

Comment: I ended up asking the guy, he said it meant, "I agree". Thank you

Comment: The expression was in common use loooong before that Cameo single.

Answer (score 12):

In his 2006 *[Roc the Mic Right: The Language of Hip Hop Culture](http://books.google.com/books?id=6yHsyYrRGOkC&pg=PA106&dq=%22yo%20word%20is%20yo%20bond%22%20%2bsmitherman&hl=en&ei=xlTMTeX7Acr50gGO5KHHBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22yo%20word%20is%20yo%20bond%22%20%2bsmitherman&f=false)*, H. Samy Alim quotes Geneva Smitherman on this use of *word*:

> The African American oral tradition is rooted in a belief in the power of the Word. The African concept of *Nommo*, the Word, is believed to be the force of life itelf. To speak is to make something come into being. Once something is given the force of speech, it is binding—hence the familiar saying "Yo word is yo bond," which in today's Hip Hop Culture has become WORD IS BORN. The Hip Hop expressions WORD, WORD UP, WORD TO THE MOTHER, and similar phrases all stem from the value placed on speech. Creative, highly verbal talkers are valued.

And the concept of someone's word being their bond is as old as dirt (or at least dates back to Shakespeare's time).

Comment: The background info here is good to know. Thank you

Comment: See also Felicia M. Miyakawa, _[Five Percenter Rap: God Hop's Music, Message, and Black Muslim Mission](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYDz9CzQtAQC&lpg=PA41&ots=VgLoLzObpM&dq=word%20is%20bond%205%20percenter&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q&f=false)_, 2005: "... the affirmations 'word' and 'word is bond,' common to hip-hop argot of the 1980s and 1990s, derive from Five Percenter lessons."

Answer (score 3):

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230192?rskey=tO4MC6&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)* says that the slang interjections **word** and **word up** are originally *U.S.*, in the language of rap and hip-hop; expressing affirmation, agreement, or admiration. However, the slang terms were used in spoken language in African-American English before it appeared in written language, starting with rap/hip-hop song lyrics.

Per *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230192?rskey=tO4MC6&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)*, the first written usage of slang *word* appeared in the lyrics of the rap song, Money (Dollar Bill, Y’all) by Jimmy Spicer, in 1981:

> Word.., that's a good record, man. 
> <sub>J. Spicer et al. *Money (Dollar Bill Y'all)* (song) in L. A. Stanley *Rap: the Lyrics* (1992) 301</sub>

and per *OED*, the first written usage of slang *word up* is from 1985:

> Just trying to stay out of trouble... Word up. 
> <sub>*N.Y. Mag.* 3 June 40/2</sub>

*[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/7ptuzwi)* provides three senses of the slang *word* and provides the only usual sense for the slang *word up*:

> **word!** *excl.* 
> *also* **word booty! word life!** 
> [abbr. word up! *excl.* + ? SE *the last word in, that’s my last word*] 
> *(orig. US black)* 
> **1.** (*also* **that’s word!**) an excl. of approval, admiration, agreement etc. 
> **2.** an expression of greeting or farewell. 
> **3.** used to signify that one is having the final say in an argument.

> **word up!** *excl.* 
> *also* **say word!** 
> *(orig. US black)* an excl. of approval, admiration, agreement etc.

*[The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.es/books?id=mAdUqLrKw4YC&pg=PA2122&dq=The%20New%20Partridge%20Dictionary%20of%20Slang%20and%20Unconventional%20English%20%22word%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwhfmg9Yz5AhXZX_EDHSfjD2UQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=The%20New%20Partridge%20Dictionary%20of%20Slang%20and%20Unconventional%20English%20%22word%20up%22&f=false)* (by Dalzell Victor Eds Staff, Eric Partridge) includes a second sense for *word up* where it is used as a greeting in the hip-hop community (like the slang *word*).

Note: *OED* provides earlier citations than both *Green’s Dictionary of Slang* and *The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*.

Answer (score 1):

***Dictionary treatments of 'word' and 'word up,' 1994–2005***

Geneva Smitherman, *Black Talk: Words and Phrases from the Hood to the Amen Corner* (1994) has two relevant entries, for *word/word up* and *word is born*:

> **WORD!/WORD UP!** A response of affirmation. Also *Word to the Mother!* *Word Up* is also the title of a music magazine published in New Jersey. [Cross reference omitted.]
>
> **WORD IS BORN!** An affirmative response to a statement or action. Also *Word!*, *Word up!*, *Word to the Mother!* A resurfacing of an old familiar saying in the Black Oral Tradition, "Yo word is yo bond," which was popularized by the FIVE PERCENT NATION [formed in 1964] in its early years. *Word is born!* reaffirms strong belief in the power of the word, and thus the value of verbal commitment. One's word is the guarantee, the warranty, the *bond*, that whatever was promised will actually occur. *Born* is a result of the A[frican] A[mrican] E[nglish] pronunciation of "bond"; [cross reference omitted].

Smitherman also has this entry for *G*:

> **G** 1) A form of address for a male, usually one who is HIP or DOWN. Probably the AAE version of "guy." Also man (older term); money (newer term). 2) A woman a man has a relationship with.

I should note that Smitherman offers this reading of *G* while fully aware of the term *OG*, which has this entry in her book:

> **OG** Original Gangster; a gang member who has earned PROPS because of his bold actions.

Clarence Major, *Juba to Jive: A Dictionary of African American Slang* (1994) has these entries:

> **Word** interj. (1950s–1990s) affirmation spoken in agreement; the truth; street culture gospel. (T[erry] W[illiams], *[The] C[ocaine] K[ids: The Inside Story of a Teenage Drug Ring* (1989)], p. 138.) Example: "Word! I was there, I aw it with my own eyes." S[outhern] C[ity] U[se], P[imp and] P[rostitute] U[se], Y[outh] C[ulture] U[se], D[rug] C[ulture] U[se].
>
> **Word up!** interj. (1980s–1990s) call for attention; used as an exression of one's word of honor. (W[illiam] K[.] B[entley and] J[ames] M[.] C[orbett], *P[rison] S[lang: Words and Expressions Depicting Life Behind Bars* (1992)], p.51.) Example: "Word up, the cops are down there right now busting Rickie." S[outhern] C[ity] U[se].

Major does not have an entry for *G* in the sense of "guy," although he does include entries for *G* as a noun meaning "a thousand dollars" (from the 1940s–1950s) and as a verb meaning "to have sexual intercourse with" (1990s). Major's entry for *O.G.* notes only its meaning (from the period 1900s–1950s) "Old Girl; mother." Smitherman dates "yo word is yo bond" to 1964, and Major dates "word" (as affirmation) to the 1950s. Nevertheless, Major's earlier *Dictionary of Afro-American Slang* (1970) has no entry for any form of *word*.

It's interesting that, publishing in the same year (1994), Professor Smitherman of Michigan State sees "Word" and "Word up" (and "Word is born") as essentially interchangeable expressions of agreement, while Professor Major of the University of California at Davis, sees "Word" as an expression of agreement but "Word up" as, in the first instance, a call for attention, and, in the second, an attestation along the lines of "I swear."

This inconstancy underscores an essential problem with defining slang words: Since they don't show up in popular use neatly predefined, they are subject to multiple interpretations by the people who hear and adopt them; as a result, it is not at all unlikely that a term may mean one thing in one locale and another in another. This phenomenon might serve as a caution to authors not to assume that a slang term's usage across a diverse but definable group (such as "African Americans") is settled and uniform—especially in its early years of propagation.

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) offers these relevant entries:

> **word 1** ***interj*** *1980s black teenagers* An exclamation of agreement and appreciation, used when someone has said something important or profound: *If it's really meaningful, "Word, man, word" should be used*—["City Teen-Agers Talking Up a 'Say What?' Storm"] *New York Times* [(August 29, 1983)] **2** ***interj*** =WORD UP
>
> **word up** ***interj*** *1980s black* An exhortation to listen, to pay attention: *Word up, fool. We be fresh tonight.*—Carsten Stroud [*Close Pursuit* (1987)] {probably based on *listen up*}

Chapman & Kipfer cites instances from the 1980s that corroborate Major's claim that "word" and "word up" had different senses in at least some parts of the United States. Nevertheless, ten years later, Jeremy Sideris & Brittany McWilliams, *From Grill to Dome: A Dictionary of African American Slang Words and Phrases* (2005) indicates that the Smitherman view (that the terms "word" and "word up" have essentially the same meaning) has prevailed in the broader marketplace of African American English speech:

> **Word:** Statement of agreement. See also *booyah*, *down*, *fo' shizzle my nizzle*, *fo' zizzle my nizzle*, *really though*, *true dat*, and *word-up*.
>
> **Word-up:** Strong statement of agreement. See also *booyah*, *down*, *fo' shizzle my nizzle*, *fo' zizzle my nizzle*, *really though*, *true dat*, and *word*.

According to Sideris & McWilliams, the only difference between the two words is in the degree of strength implied in the statement of agreement.

---

***A note on 'word is bond'***

With regard to Smitherman's comment that "yo word is yo bond" is "an old familiar saying in the Black Oral Tradition," that familiarity may be due to the fact that the same essential idea has been a proverb in English since at least 1500. From Fred Shapiro, *The Yale Book of Quotations* (2006):

> A man's word is his bond. *Lancelot of Lake* (ca. 1500). This source, with the wording "o kingis word shuld be o kingis bonde," is the earliest version given by the *Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs*.

The first several citations from the full entry for this proverb in J.A. Simpson, *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs* (1982) deserve mention:

> **An Englishman's word is his bond** *c* **1500** *Lancelot of Lake* (STS) l. 1671 O kingis word shuld be o kingis bonde. *a* **1606** Nobody and Somebody C2<sup>v</sup> Nobodis worde is as good as his bond. **1642** T[homas] Fuller *Holy State* v. xiii. He hath this property of an honest man, that his word is as good as his band. **1754** [Samuel] Richardson *[The History of Sir Charles] Grandison* I. Letter ix. I am no flincher ... The word of Sir Rowland Meredith is as good as his bond. **1841** [Charles] Dickens *[The] Old Curiosity Shop* lviii. 'Marchioness,' said Mr. Shriveller [Swiveller, actually], rising, 'the word of a gentleman is as good as his bond—sometimes better, as in the present case.' **1924** G. Benham *Book of Quotations* (rev. ed.) 735 (Proverb) An Englishman's word is his bond.

I have no doubt that, as Smitherman asserts, an adage along the lines of "Your word is your bond" was common among black families in the United States long before "word" appeared as (arguably) a truncated form of the same idea. But it also seems highly likely that the wording entered the pool of African American English folk wisdom from a proverb that originated in England.

Answer (score 0):

Well [this Yahoo answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070620103246AA5SqNk) claims that it comes from "word of God" (meaning the Bible), and used to mean swearing on a Bible.

The "G", though, is most probably for "Gangsta". "OG", for example, stands for "Original Gangsta".