# What is the etymology of "word!"

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang

Many people have begun to use the word "word" seemingly as an exclamation point or as a means to be emphatic.

Where and why did this begin?

Comment: Urban Dictionary says it came from a shortening of "My word is my bond," meaning you were speaking the truth. However, UD isn't the most reliable source, and I'd be skeptical about that theory until I found something more credible to back it up.

Comment: [Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Word) gives lots of examples of this usage.

Comment: Wiktionary (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/word#Interjection) also gives the Urban Dictionary's etymology. I'd trust it more than I would UD, but not everyone does.

Comment: I'm thinking this topic came up about 2 months ago.

Comment: The definition given in Urban Dictionary and Wiktionary sound very reasonable. Generally I'd trust UD as far as I could throw it, and Wiki as far as it pointed me at something I could trust, but this does seem plausible. Then again, most provably nonsense folk etymologies seem plausible too. "My word!" could be a source too. (Which in turn comes from your word as something to promise by).

Comment: @JonHanna I don't understand the idiom in the case of Wiktionary. Do you trust it as long as it points you toward something you can trust? Or something else?

Comment: @JonathanSpirit I don't trust it at all, but I do sometimes find it a useful starting point. (Actually, I think it's a very good work-a-day dictionary, but if I wasn't sure about something I wouldn't consider it conclusive either way).

Comment: @JonHanna It's usually what I look to for complete etymologies, especially since it goes all the way back to proto languages, and it's the only reliable and complete source of words for Latin with all forms.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the title of this question to "What is the etymology of "Word!"

Comment: I'll bet this question has been asked before, but searching for "word" on a site about language isn't going to be useful.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit me too if I don't have access to the OED, but if it doesn't cite I wouldn't be fully confident in it; but then much of the time I'm just curious and my curiosity is content with the results.

Comment: @Barmar [Turns out you’re right!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25086/what-are-the-meaning-and-possible-origin-of-word-and-word-up) (Though I’m not exactly impressed by any of the answers there, and that question also deals with the meaning, rather than just the origin.)

Comment: At UD, The Chunk's take on things (#32) seems accurate to me.

Comment: This question also duplicates [What does the expression "Word." mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218351/what-does-the-expression-word-mean/218444#218444) from a couple of weeks ago. That question is still open, but it should probably be closed for the same reason this one was; it does have a couple of thoughtful answers (one by me).

Answer (score 3):

Word!

Dig a bit deeper into the Urban Dictionary and you will find this:

> **word to your mother:** An anachronistic corruption of the phrase "word to the mother", which was a popular reference to Africa or "The Motherland" during the late 1980s Afrocentric movement. While the replacement of "the" with "your" effectively obliterated the term's Afrocentric roots, it continued to be used in the same manner, that is, to express agreement. Alternatively, the "your" could take on sinister connotations, implying that speaker was sexually intimate with the listener's mother, as in "say hi to your mom for me", or, in keeping with the whack terminology, "props to your mom, she's da bomb". Finally, the phrase might mean nothing at all, and be used to ineptly feign street cred, in the style of Vanilla Ice.

FYI: Big Daddy Kane has a song "Word to the Mother(Land)," which you can hear *[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96KOe99gO7M)*.

You will also find this explanation in *[Roc the Mic Right: The Language of Hip Hop Culture](http://books.google.ca/books?id=6yHsyYrRGOkC&pg=PA106&dq=%22yo%20word%20is%20yo%20bond%22%20%2Bsmitherman&hl=en&ei=xlTMTeX7Acr50gGO5KHHBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22yo%20word%20is%20yo%20bond%22%20%2Bsmitherman&f=false)*:

> The African American oral tradition is rooted in a belief in the power of the Word. The African concept of Nommo, the Word, is believed to be the force of life itelf. To speak is to make something come into being. Once something is given the force of speech, it is binding—hence the familiar saying "Yo word is yo bond," which in today's Hip Hop Culture has become WORD IS BORN. The Hip Hop expressions WORD, WORD UP, WORD TO THE MOTHER, and similar phrases all stem from the value placed on speech. Creative, highly verbal talkers are valued.

This supports the comment from UD that it came from "my word is my bond," or a reasonable facsimile of the expression, but only in part. In 20th/21st century African American culture, "word" collocates broadly and creatively, and untangling its Genesis is a tricky business.

Comment: @Erik: the capitalization of "Genesis" was intentional. A playful reference. In the beginning was the...

Comment: @RustyTuba - Sorry about that — I missed the allusion. I'll change it back.

Comment: @Erik: .... word!

Comment: Alternatively, it may be derived from "Your word is your bond"—an expression that goes back more than a century. See my answer at "[What does the expression "Word." mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218351/what-does-the-expression-word-mean/218444#218444)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to *My word* used as an exclamation, or expression of incredulity etc?

If so I am wondering why this comes with the suggestion that it is something new. I have heard it used all my life.

It is dealt with by the OED with examples since 1722.

***my word (esp. as an exclamation) = upon my word at Phrases 1g(b)(ii)***.

*Now chiefly as upon my word (also 'pon my word: see pon prep.). As an asseveration: assuredly, certainly, truly, indeed. In later use also as a simple exclamation of surprise or strong emotion.* ***Now somewhat arch.***

> 1722   A. Philips Briton ii. iii. 14   He loves thee, Gwendolen:—My
>   word, he does.
>
> 1821   London Mag. June 658/2   When the New Town Christeners had
>   exhausted their Georges and Charlottes and Fredericks and Hanovers,
>   (and, my word, they did extend the royalty).
>
> 1841   E. C. Gaskell Lett. (1966) 44   My word! authorship brings them
>   in a pretty penny.
>
> 1857   F. Locker London Lyrics 72   Half London was there, and, my
>   word, there were few..But envied Lord Nigel's felicity.
>
> 1874   Trollope Harry Heathcote ii. 49   ‘You dropped the match by
>   accident?’ ‘My word, no. Did it o' purpose to see.’
>
> 1932   P. Hamilton Siege of Pleasure in Twenty Thousand Streets under
>   Sky (1935) ii. 62   ‘My word!’ said Violet. ‘You didn't half give me a
>   turn.’
>
> 1960   C. Day Lewis Buried Day ii. 43   My word, how we did dress up
>   in those days!
>
> 2004   G. Woodward I'll go to Bed at Noon xiii. 237   ‘That's an old
>   Vincent,’ said Janus Brian, ‘my word. Haven't seen one of those for
>   years’.

Comment: The *"word!"* the OP is asking about doesn't mean the same thing. It means something like *"absolutely right"*, and is American slang.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm intrigued. Can you give me an example of how it would be used, please?

Comment: The OP asked about its meaning "as an exclamation point or as a means to be emphatic" which WS2 addresses. The question has no quotations that contradict this. That's why I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: @WS2 There are a few examples in the [Wiktionary article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/word#Interjection) (click the “quotations” link to expand) that show common usage. See also [_word up_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/word_up), which means more or less the same in this context.

Comment: An example would be simply to say: 'Word.' (with or without exclamation) in response to something someone else says that they agree with or some such.